# How to write into Photo Library on Mac?

Tags: swift, macos

Is it possible to write directly into the Photo Library for example an image on MacOs using Swift?

The only thing I have found is the Photo Kit where is a class named `PHAssetCreationRequest` which provides methods for writing into the photo library. But it is in Beta state.

Are some stable versions out there to write directly into the Photo Library?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you are able to do it through AppleScript.  See its Dictionary.

Comment: @ElTomato do you have an example for writing directly into the photo library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, `PHAssetCreationRequest` is the only API for writing photos to the macOS photo library, and it's only available on macOS 10.15 and later. There's also a `MediaLibrary` API for read-only access.

Typically, macOS apps don't save photos directly to the photo library. Instead they should allow users to save files to wherever they want, and the user can either:

- save file to a specific location (see [File Handling Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/user-interaction/file-handling/)), or
- drag and drop to an app or folder (see [Drag and Drop Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/user-interaction/drag-and-drop/))

For example, if the user wants to import into their photos library, they should be able to drag multiple images from your app and drop them on the Photos icon in the dock to import them.

Comment: As Feared. So there is no workaround? The user must be involved into the process? Thank you.

Comment: Correct, there is no API except for the new one.